# Well in Angular JS innerHTML or innerText is not working in ng-keypress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

In Angular Js i am using a onkeypress instead of that going to change the ng-keypress but innerHTML and innerText is not working.

code:
`<div id="test" onkeypress="return (this.innerHTML.length <= 15)"/>`

Comment: ngKeypress ! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

Comment: Why would you want to have keypress event on "div" tag?

Comment: I will type the text in div tag if it exceeds more than 15 it stop to edit it. I like to convert into angular because going to change javascript to angular.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nezdn8Ld/ check this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="test" ng-keypress="return (this.innerHTML.length <= 15)"/>
```

in angular js we have to use 
ng prefix for the events

[refrence..](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)